# multiple buttons exist. how to make a unique text intended for each button appear after it is clicked

Tags: javascript

a piece of code that shows a piece of text after the button is clicked, how would I use that code for multiple buttons with each button giving a unique piece of text. how to position the outputted text. And how to make the text replace the one from the previous text from another button.  Thank you so much!

```
<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clear your question? Do you want show show different text based on different button on same <p> element?

Comment: There are several questions asked.  Can you refine this to just one question?  Also, formatting and capitalization helps.

Answer (score 2):

Pass some data on button click handler to identify which text to show. Below is a working example.

```js
var lines = ["Demo text line one", "This is line two", "And this is 3rd and final line"];
var speed = 50;
var elim = document.getElementById("demo");
function showText(btnId) {
  var text = lines[btnId - 1];
  var printer = setInterval(printChar, speed);
  var i = 0;
  function printChar() {
    if (i > text.length) {
      clearInterval(printer);
    } else {
      elim.innerHTML = text.slice(0, i);
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="showText(1)">One</button>
<button onclick="showText(2)">Two</button>
<button onclick="showText(3)">Three</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 different questions, but I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
<!-- Here you can pass a parameter with the desired text -->
<button onclick="writeText('Text 01')">Click me</button>
<button onclick="writeText('Text 02')">Or click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = '';
var speed = 50;

// This new helper function will be used to clear time and previous text
function writeText(newTxt) {
  i = 0;
  txt = newTxt;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  typeWriter();
}

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the working example: https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/YzKREdr?editors=1000

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me.  My last question is how to position the outputted text to another part of the page, because right now it just appears at the bottom of my picture.  tnx again!

Comment: Glad to know it helped you! To position your text somewhere else, you could use the HTML structure or CSS. Can you update your question with the HTML code and a specification of where you want the text?